# Experience with Geoserver's GML Extension

Tags: geoserver, rest, gml

I'd like to know if [Geoserver's GML extension](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/gml.html) works (well) with GeoServer 2.1-RC2 and whether it will enable uploading of GML files via REST API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the GML extension has more or less been abandoned due to lack of a maintainer for that extension. That said you can still upload GML as part of a WFS transaction. So a recipe that could work is to create a new empty layer (in postgis or something) via the REST api, and then issue WFS transactions to populate it.

Comment: Thanks jdeolive. I'm trying to avoid creation of a PostGIS layer just for the sake of displaying the GML contents (that may change with each request).